# Visa, when changing planes

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, transit

I am travelling From San Francisco to New Delhi via Amsterdam (Schiphol AMS). I have Indian passport and a valid US visa on it. Do I need any kind of visa in Schiphol airport. There is 3 hours of break before I catch my flight from AMS to New Delhi. 
And also please tell me if I need any visa while coming back from New Delhi to San Francisco.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Terminology...  It's not about 'changing planes', it's about 'transit visas'.  Perhaps if you researched on that term you would find a lot of relevant information. For this site, your question has a canonical answer already.  Close voting as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I get a simple answer as YES or NO ? I got it that I should write VISA as visa and I got it that its not 'changing planes' and its all about 'transit visa'. Now please tell me when I will get down at AMS and wait there for next flight. Do I need any kind of visa or its all fine to roam inside airport without any visa.

Comment: @Blrfl: I didn’t say the company name was an acronym, only that the styling “VISA” makes one think of the company (because of their all-caps logo, of course). – Anyway, since the question was since edited to correct “VISA” into “visa”, I’m going to delete my previous comment.